# call controller in grails from view

Tags: grails, view, controller

I have an controller (controllerA) that calls to a view (viewA) and I need that when the view show it, call to other controller (controllerB). Is it possible?

I know that this is possible with a button or link, but I need do this when the view show it.

Any suggestions?

[EDIT]

I have tried to use `remoteFunction` but I don't resolve my problem.

I have this controller:

```
class ProgresBarController {
    def showProgressA() {
        [progressBarInstance: new ProgressBar(num: 23, mess: "message")]
    }

    def showProgressB() {
        print "I am in showProgressB"
        def progressBarInstance = new ProgressBar(num: 50, mess: "mensaje2")
        render(view: "showProgressB", model: [progressBarInstance: progressBarInstance])
    }
```

I call to showProgressA() and the method shows the view showProgressA. In the view, I have a javascript code in event `onload` of the tag body and it calls to the method showProgressB() and print "I am in showProgressB" but the controller don't show the view of showProgressB.

The code of javascript is this:

```
<body onload="${ remoteFunction(action:'showProgressB')}">
```

What is the problem? :(

Comment: If you want to go from a controller to another controller you might need to use `redirect`. After a view is rendered you need some sort of event to trigger it going to other actions.

Comment: Can you say me an example please? Really, I need to show a view while a controller does his action. When the controller finishes the action, redirect to other controller and shows the same view.

Comment: Please explain more about your scenario.

Comment: I have a view with a form. When I submit the form, a controller does his action. I would like that while this controller does his action show a view. When the controller finishes his job, the view redirect to other controller and repeat the process.

Comment: Can I show a view before controller finishes his action? I know shows a view when the controller finishes but not before. It's possible? maybe this will resolve my problem.

Comment: Sure, you can call your actions using ajax request and still be on your page or render another page. Take a look at `remoteFunction` and `remoteLink`. You can also roll your own request using jquery ajax lib.

Comment: I edit my post and I comment that I did it with `remoteFunction` but I don't resolve the problem. :(